# Частицы "то, либо, нибудь, кое"

Tags: грамматика

*В другой теме возник вопрос в отношении этих "школьных" частиц.
Решил подстраховаться на случай своей отсталости от жизни и задать его тут.*

***Частицы "то", "либо", "нибудь", "кое" ведь не перестают быть частицами в составе неопределенных местоимений и наречий типа "где-либо", "кто-то", "как-нибудь"?***

Ни в школе, ни у Розенталя не помню ничего, что давало бы повод усомниться, что эти частицы - всегда частицы.
И тут вдруг некий источник если не прямо, то косвенно называет эти частицы в составе неопределенных наречий постфиксами (но не частицами), оставляя, правда, им право быть частицами в остальных случаях.
http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=c8641dbf-8500-479b-b1ba-6176fcf59d35

Я чего-то не понимаю или теперь так учат?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Термин частица является буквальным переводом латинского слова particula и употребляется в языкознании в двух значениях: широком – когда к частицам речи уже 200 лет относят все служебные части речи, противопоставляя их знаменательным частям речи (А.А. Шахматов, Л.В. Щерба, В.В. Виноградов).

Более 100 лет назад (в 1897 г.) впервые в русской и зарубежной лингвистике ученый Добиаш назвал частицу самостоятельной частью речи и отграничил ее от других служебных слов. С тех пор термин частица употребляется и в узком значении – для именования конкретной части речи.

Вы ( и я тоже)учились ещё по учебникам Виноградова и его учеников, там слово частица употреблялось в широком значении. В то же время мы учили:
•   Части́ца — служебная часть речи, которая вносит различные значения, эмоциональные оттенки в предложение, сочетание, слово или служит для образования форм слова.

Виноградов  выделил 8 разрядов частиц:
1.  Усилительно-ограничительные, или выделительные частицы: только, лишь,хоть.
2.  Присоединительные частицы: тоже, также.
3.  Определительные частицы: именно,подлинно, как раз.
4.  Указательные частицы: вот, вон, это.
5.  Неопределённые частицы: -то, -либо, -нибудь, кое-.
6.  Количественные частицы: почти, ровно,точно.
7.  Отрицательные частицы: не и ни.
8.  Модально-глагольные частицы: бы, да, хоть бы, лишь бы.

Шанский Н. М. и Тихонов А. Н. выделяют четыре разряда частиц по значению: смысловые, модальные, эмоционально-экспрессивные, формообразующие.

Уже тогда говорили: служебные слова могут превращаться в аффиксы словообразовательного и формообразовательного типа. Это наблюдается, когда служебное слово становится неотделимым от знаменательного слова и изменяет его значение(неопред. местоимения)

А сейчас язык изучается в современном состоянии, т.е.то-, либо-, нибудь-, кое- это уже не служебные слова, а аффиксы, участвующие в словообразовании, поэтому их совершенно верно называют постфиксами, а в школе, чтобы младших школьников не путать, суффиксами.

Иногда всё-таки хочется назвать их частицами в широком смысле. Вот как, например, объяснить раздельное написание:Если между частицей кое- (кой-) и местоимением есть предлог, то все сочетание пишется раздельно: кое от кого, кое на чем, кой у кого, кое с чьим. Если сказать, что между приставкой и местоимением может стоять предлог и тогда оно пишется отдельно от них, будет звучать странно, вот и приходится обращаться к старым терминам. Здесь "кое" именно частица. А в начальной форме (кое-кто) - приставка.

Comment: Я немножечко уточню. Я учился, когда выделяли 12 частей речи: пять имен (существительное, прилагательное, причастие, числительное, местоимение), глагол, наречие, деепричастие союз, междометие, предлог и частица. Так что частицами никак не могли называть все служебные слова. Про них, правда, говорили, что теория частиц еще только начинает разрабатываться, но с прочими служебными явно не смешивали.

Answer (score 0):

Все намного проще. Частица — служебная часть речи, новое слово она не образует, вносит только оттенок значения.
В образовании неопределенных местоимений участвуют морфемы (части слова), поэтому **КОЕ-** — это приставка; **-ТО, -либо, -нибудь** — суффиксы.
Но есть и частица **-ТО**, которая вносит оттенок смягчения: работу-то сделал? При этом новое слово не образуется.